# Extract a list item in Python that contains a string, without list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, indexing, list-comprehension

Given a list:

```
my_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

I want to extract the element that contains 'ab' (of which there will only ever be one).

Rather than something a little convoluted like:

```
[i for i in my_list if 'ab' in i][0]
```

I'm looking for some way of applying something that does the equivalent of XPath `contains()`, but for a list.

Comment: *of which there will only ever be one* --- Use genexp `(i for i in my_list if 'ab' in i).next()`

Comment: I like it @BhargavRao, but is it less convoluted than the list comprehension? Also, the list comprehension is pretty concise and I would argue that it is not in fact convoluted. If you want it to be more clear, write a function, put comments in the function.

Comment: @RobertB I read the line which is highlighted in my comment and then I commented. Gen-exp here is better than list comp only because it need not create the complete list and can return the first result. Hence it can be faster. However it is not *answer worthy*, hence I left it as a comment. Thanks and All the best.

Comment: @BhargavRao, At first I was of the opinion that "complete list" was only ever 1 element, so it didn't matter. However, the list comprehension will still always traverse the entire source list even it already found a match, whereas the generator solution will not.  So the genexp is more efficient after all. Point conceded. "Less convoluted" though, I think is arguable still LOL

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned about iterating through the entire list:

```
In [50]: L = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

In [51]: next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda s: 'ab' not in s, L))
Out[51]: 'abc'
```

Don't forget to `import itertools`

Comment: `takewhile` is much more natural

Comment: @JBernardo: but if the target string is not at the head of the list, `takewhile` will not work

Comment: Actually `dropwhile` is wrong. Try `list(...)` instead of `next(...)`

Comment: Why is `dropwhile` wrong? Also, OP doesn't want a full list, just the first occurrence - which we are assured will exist

Comment: So whenever OP wants the second element matching 'ab' he is out of luck and must reimplement this code. There are many things more useful than that e.g. `next(thing for thing in L if 'ab' in thing)`

Comment: But there is no second match: `there will only ever be one`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

```
>>> my_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
>>> filter(lambda x: 'ab' in x, my_list)
['abc']
>>>
```

You can also create a function which can call a list:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> my_ab_func = partial(filter, lambda x: 'ab' in x)
>>> my_ab_func(my_list)
['abc']
>>> my_list2 = ['dabd', 'no','yes', 'zyx']
>>> my_ab_func(my_list2)
['dabd']
>>>
```

Comment: `lambda` functions, I would argue, are **more** convoluted than the comprehension. And to get the element, you still have do [0] at the end.

Comment: I wanted to point out the use of `filter` which is straightforward. I feel lambda is not a **necessity** but it looks intuitive here. In fact the documentation of [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) uses the same example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ifilter` from `itertools`, it returns iterator instead of list:

```
from itertools import ifilter

my_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']  

next(ifilter(lambda x: 'ab' in x, my_list))
```

Comment: the correct usage should be: `next(ifilter(...))`. The `.next` method is highly deprecated

Comment: I guess I argue that the comprehension is convoluted. But if one argues that it is, I would argue that a lambda function is more so.

Answer (score 1):

> Rather than something a little convoluted like:
>
> ```py
> [i for i in my_list if 'ab' in i][0]
> ```

List comprehension is very much idiomatic for Python. If your lists are small, what you have is [probably sufficient](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) with some additional error checking:

```py
def lcontains(needle_s, haystack_l):
    try: return [i for i in haystack_l if needle_s in i][0]
    except IndexError: return None

# Example use:
lcontains('ab', my_list)
```

That being said, if your input lists (or more generally, iterables) are potentially large, you might consider using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```py
import itertools

try:
    irange = xrange # Python 2
    ifilter = itertools.ifilter
except NameError:
    irange = range # Python 3
    ifilter = filter

def oneornone(iterable):
    try: return iterable.next()
    except StopIteration: return None

icontains = lambda predicate_f, haystack_i: oneornone(ifilter(predicate_f, haystack_i))

# Example use:
result = icontains(lambda i: i % 3323 == 0, irange(2, 1000000000000, 5))

# Or, in your case:
result = icontains(lambda i: 'ab' in i, mylist)
```